# Valid m3u8 file can't play on mobile

Tags: ios, http, video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a server running locally that serves valid .m3u8 and .ts files. If I open up the file on safari (desktop) it will begin to play the stream just fine, however, if I open the file on mobile on the same network (in safari or in an AVPlayer on iOS), It fails to play. As far as I can tell, it isn't a network issue because I can see that the mobile browser sends a request to the server for the manifest, then the second, then it begins requesting video segments, but they never play. I believe that the issue is with my manifest files because if I replace the URL with a valid .m3u8 file ([example](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8)) it will play just fine.

My manifest files:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=96
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=96
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=128
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=128
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=192
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=192
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=256
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=256
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=320
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=320
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=512
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=512
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1024
../../d/stream.m3u8?b=1024
```

From there it requests the second manifest from the server:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2,
../m/file1.ts
#EXTINF:2,
../m/file2.ts
#EXTINF:2,
../m/file3.ts
#EXTINF:2,
../m/file4.ts
#EXTINF:2,
../m/file5.ts
```

The device then requests a segment, but it never displays it.

Comment: Different devices support different codecs and formats - if you provide a link to the video causing the problem it should be possible to see if this is the issue.

Comment: Yes! That's it. I checked the codecs of my segments and it's using MPEG2 video and MPEG2 audio as its codecs. I changed them to AAC and H264 and it's working now. Thank you!